# Не работает пробел в /say discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Доброе утро, я делаю своего бота на discord.py, и у меня есть команда `/say`.
Сначала я в ней просто писал по одному слову, но когда написал что-то с пробелом то оно мне выдало вот это:

[image: вместо пробела {text}]

Кто может помочь, код:

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *args):
    embed = discord.Embed(description = "{text}".join(args), color=0x8A2BE2)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Код корявый, на раз два сделан, рабочий но пробелы не работают

Comment: Если нужно через пробел соединить, укажите пробел как разделитель join: `" ".join(args)`. Не понятно вообще, зачем вы туда `{text}` воткнули.

Comment: Почитайте: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82